# Error when connecting to Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-cloud-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

Every time I try to add Firebase Cloud Messaging(FCM) to my app. I am getting this error. One of the posts on this platform says you have change to the latest version which is 17.0.1. However, when I do that I am still getting the error.

This is the error:

> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this version for the implementation of the **Firebase cloud messaging** service

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4
```

Because at the official site of Firebase there is mention 17.3.4 version

**See below**

[image]